InstructionError(3 , IncorrectProgramId): swap transactions weird error
I have been encountering this error when trying to create swap transactions on pump.fun, anyone knows how to fix or why its happening? And the strangest thing is that, strangely, sometimes it happens and sometimes the swap lands with no errors.
SimulateTransactionResp { 
    context: RpcResponseContext { slot: 302378098, api_version: Some("1.18.22") },
    value: RpcSimulateTransactionResult(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(3, IncorrectProgramId)),
    logs: Some([
       "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
       "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
       "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
       "Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success",
       "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]",
       "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success",
       "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]",
       "Program log: Create",
       "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]",
       "Program log: Instruction: GetAccountDataSize",
       "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId",
       "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 884 of 56036 compute units",
       "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction",
       "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 12398 of 67550 compute units",
       "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id for instruction"
    ]),
    accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(12848), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None })
}


Can you check that you are passing in all the correct accounts and that they are initialized on the cluster you are working on. Perhaps you might be passing in a token account not yet initialized.
